# piping and redirecting weird result

Tags: shell, command-line, pipe, io-redirection

Considering 2 json files:

`fileA.json`:

```
{
  "foo": "hey",
  "bar": "ola"
}
```

`fileB.json`:

```
{
  "foo": "hoy"
}
```

, executing:

```
% cat fileA.json fileB.json | json
```

returns

```
{
  "foo": "hoy",
  "bar": "ola"
}
```

Ok

--

Now why when redirecting stdout to `fileB.json` I get:

```
% cat fileA.json fileB.json | json > fileB.json
```

I get:

```
{
  "foo": "hey",
  "bar": "ola"
}
```

Ie: `fileA.json` ???

PS: `json` utility is here: http://trentm.com/json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell sets up output redirection, `> fileB.json`, so it opens and truncates `fileB.json` before `cat` has started reading from it. This causes `cat` to read an empty file. (It might even end up reading partially written output data.)

Never read from and write to the same file in a pipeline. Try something like `> fileC.json` instead.